# How can i embed an external form in a hubspot landing page?

Tags: hubspot

I have been trying to embed an external form on my hubspot landing pages. Can anyone please tell me how to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed any html form using the **Custom HTML** module.
http://knowledge.hubspot.com/design-manager-user-guide-v2/hubspots-standard-modules-explained
But you will have to use an absolute URL on the form action=, and the user will leave hubspot on submit.

Or you could use an **iFrame**, again in Custom HTML module. Both the form and the result page can then be hosted externally.